# Avatica Calcite JDBC Driver issue

Tags: java, jdbc, druid, apache-calcite

I am getting the below error while trying to getConnection through Java Web App. Any one faced this issue ?

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class 
org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Service$ResultSetResponse not subtype of 
[simple type, class 
org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Service$RpcMetadataResponse]
at [Source: {"response":"openConnection","rpcMetadata":{"
```

Code:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver"); 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:avatica:remote:url=XXXX ");
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We may need some more details concerning the libs you use, java version etc.

Comment: Class.forName("org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver");
try {
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:avatica:remote:url=http:XXXX");
 } catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}


JDK 1.8 and the web app is running on JBOSS

Answer (score 0):

When you're using JDBC driver from Java web application, you're not supposed to give DriverManager a link to Avatica, but to specific database.

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:avatica:remote:url=XXXX ");
```

Instead, just use:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:", info);
```

and it will work.